# How can I have multiple exception in a single throw java docs tag?

Tags: java, javadoc, throw

I am trying to add a JavaDoc in my code. I need to add multiple exception in a single throw. When I add below, it only recognizes `NullPointerException` not the `IllegalArgumentException`. Is there any way to provide multiple exception in a single throw tag so that it can recognize both, when I place my mouse on the method?

```
@throws NullPointerException, IllegalArgumentException when invalid userId, timeout is passed
```

Or I need to do it like this? By this, I am repeating same comment twice.

```
@throws NullPointerException when invalid userId, timeout is passed
@throws IllegalArgumentException when invalid userId, timeout is passed
```

Comment: Yes, you need 2 `@throws` tags. Similar to how you need 2 `@param` tags if your method has 2 parameters

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You cannot specify 2 exceptions with 1 `@throws` tag

---

You need a `@throws` tag for each exception you have. This allows you to give a description for each exception you are throwing.